# How to select and extract a specific text from a PDF using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am developing a chrome extension to extract a highlighted text from a PDF.

I there any way to accomplish this task using javascript? I am able to select text from HTML pages, however, I am not able to do the same from PDF files opened in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, you have to convert the PDF file to a document (editable) before selecting the desired portion using slice(x, y) by JavaScript

Comment: That technique would not be desirable for my use.